# vscode to pick up node js not from enviroment path but from a usb folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

I installed nodejs in a usb folder H:\nodejs\node-v16.14.2-win-x86\node

and when I do

H:\nodejs\node-v16.14.2-win-x86\node testing.js

it works. But how can set vscode in a way that it points to my usb folder?

I got it work with python with

"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "H:\python\python.exe",

I dont wanna use enviroment variable and want to point it directly to a specific folder in my usb that has nodejs installed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

VS Code looks for "Node" on your path, and why would it do it any other way, its platform specific. If VS Code is running in Linux, Mac, or Windows, it won't run.

#### Not All is Lost for You Though...

Just because VS Code uses your systems path to exec VS Code, which BTW is an official standard for calling executable, doesn't mean you cannot configure the path, using a symbolic link or something like that, to call your executable from your USB.

2BH, the easiest way to get your USB to 'plug n execute' would be to write a piece of software that configures your OS path to execute node from the USB (this is sort of similar to what drivers are for, when you install other hardware, which is sort of what your USB is right?).

You would probably need to write it in **MVSC C++**, since your on windows. Linux is a far better OS to do stuff like what your doing. You could easily configure your `~/.bashrc` to find the executable.

Those are your options though. Its important that you acknowledge how important standards are, if for no other reason than the sake of manifesting your ideas into something useful. If it were not for contemporary standards, which took a hell of a lot of work, and years to put into place (not to mention legal humps to climb over), computers, and programming languages, wouldn't be nearly as useful, or as technologically advanced as the state that you find them in today.

The path on your system is an extremely fundamental standard and concept. It isn't the only option you have for calling executables, which is what you are using to run node from your USB, but it is by far the most used, and for good reason. I want to explain why but its really far beyond the scope of this question. Its cool what your trying to do, so I wanted to help you if I could.

Try to read about using symbolic links with the path. If your clever enough, you could probably get much closer to what you want using symbolic links combined with the system path.

Comment: Thanks somuch for your input! While going through your comment I had this idea in theory to pull this off and wanna know about your take on it. Creating a linux vm in a USB and just run everything from there? Then I suppose it gets rid of the problem of having to do anything with the host computer and run everything from the usb.

Are there any python.defaultInterpreterPath equivalent in node? I've been running python straight from the usb this way by pointing it to the python.exe directory. Or like you said, "VS Code looks for "Node" on your path" therefore its not the case for node.